# Error in import commands from another file in Python in discord bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I working on a bot project for discord and I bareless start, I wrote the commands in another file but when a start the bot and run the command, show this:

```
    Ignoring exception in command None:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "nameCommand" is not found
```

The file wheres my commands at is that:

```
class Comandos:

    def cumprimento(self):
        return self.channel.send("Olá,sou Fego! O Robô espacial!")
    
    def historia(self):
        return self.channel.send("Eu existo há apenas alguns dias!")
```

And the principal file where the bot's running is that:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from comandos import Comandos


bot = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='fg.')

cmd = Comandos()

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged as {0.user}'.format(bot))

@bot.on_message
async def on_message(message):
    message.channel.content = message.channel.content.lower()
    if message.author.bot:
        return
    if message.content.startswith("fg."):
        try:
            if message.content('cumprimento'):
                await message.channel.send(cmd.cumprimento)
            elif message.content('historia'):
                await message.channel.send(cmd.historia)
        except:
            await message.channel.send('Comando não existe!')
   
bot.run(token)
```

I tried many alternatives, like put @bot.commands in the commands file, or iterate looping in the file and compare the arg with the name of each function, I honestly have no idea about what to do.

Comment: You're trying to invoke a command that doesn't exist, because you have never added the command to the bot. I'd suggest reading the official example because a couple of things in your code don't make a lot of sense: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/cogs.html for cogs, and https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#commands-extension for regular commands

Comment: Thank you! Actually, these links help me a lot, apreciatte that

Answer (score 0):

In order to register a command, you have to add the decorator @bot.command before each function. [This registers the command to the bot.](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=bot#discord.ext.commands.Bot.command)

Also, I have a few other suggestions regarding your bot but not your current problem. I believe that each function has to have `async` preceding the `def` keyword in order to make the function run asynchronously.
Example:

```py
@bot.command()
async def cuprimento(self):
    return self.channel.send("Olá,sou Fego! O Robô espacial!")
```

Furthermore, when you call `await message.channel.send(cmd.historia)`, this translates to `await message.channel.send(self.channel.send("Eu existo há apenas alguns dias!"))`. Basically, you are already sending the message when you call the function, so you don't need to send that. You can fix this by either only returning text or only calling the function.

Sending the message from the function:

```py
@bot.command()
def cuprimento(self):
    return "Olá,sou Fego! O Robô espacial!"

#existing code

if message.content('cuprimento'):
    await message.channel.send(cmd.cuprimento())
```

Returning text from the function:

```py
@bot.command()
def cuprimento(self):
    await self.channel.send("Olá,sou Fego! O Robô espacial!")

#existing code

if message.content('cuprimento'):
    cmd.cuprimento()
```

Comment: The code looks better but still didn't work, I will working on that, but, thanks for awnser!

Comment: Could you give more details so I can try to help more? If you prefer, you could read the docs linked by stijndcl as those are probably more comprehensive.